# React is not rendering when i use react-router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set-up routers with react and webpack, I have added **historyApiFallback: true,** to my webpack config file, and then I'm just trying to use router on my App.js which is rendered correctly without router, but when I add the component `<Router>` or whatever its related to I get nothing rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;

const About = () => <div>About</div>;

const App = () => (
<Router>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/about">About</Link>

  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Router>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Switch` that, as `react-router-dom` says:

> A Switch looks through its children s and renders the first
> one that matches the current URL.

So your code becomes:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
Link,
Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;

const About = () => <div>About</div>;

const App = () => (
<Router>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
     <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
);

export default App;
```

You could see [this](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing) example.

Comment: While im using the new version of react-router , i used <Routes> instead of <Switch> and i had the same problem , maybe i should downgrade the actual version ?

Comment: @IlyesNegadi Sorry, I never used Routes (always Switch) but you could try to downgrade and check if problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

## `react-router-dom@5`

If using `react-rotuer-dom` v5 then I don't see any issue with the code, it should render without issue. You may want to render the routes into the `Switch` component though so you are matching and rendering a single route at-a-time.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;

const About = () => <div>About</div>;

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

## `react-router-dom@6`

If using `react-router-dom` v6 then you ***need*** to render the routes into the `Routes` component and render the routed components on the `element` prop as the `Route` component API changed; there's no longer the `component` and `render` and `children` function props. The `element` prop takes a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Routes,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;

const About = () => <div>About</div>;

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>

    <Routes>
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);
```